# Datacontext conflicts

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext

```
<UserControl x:Class="WatermarkTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="30"
             d:DesignWidth="250">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border>
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Watermark, FallbackValue=This prompt dissappears as you type...}"
                       Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtUserEntry"
                     Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

The above code shows my `WatermarkTextBox` control. In the code behind file I have set the `DataContext`. I left out all the code for the DP's of the control.

```
public WatermarkTextBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid.DataContext = this;
}
```

I had to bind the `DataContext` to the grid because otherwise the `Text` properties of both the watermark and actual text wouldn't display. The problem now is that I can't set the `Background` of the `Border` outside of the `Grid`.

I tried the code below but then only the `Background` of the `Border` is set and not the watermark and actual text.

```
public WatermarkTextBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    grid.DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a UserControl like this you should never exlicitly set the DataContext to `this` or anyting else, because the DataContext is usually set externally when you use the UserControl somewhere in your application. The externally applied DataContext is typically (part of) the application's view model.

You should instead change your internal bindings so that they use an explicit `RelativeSource`:

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding Path=Watermark,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                   FallbackValue=This prompt dissappears as you type...}"
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry,
                         Path=Text.IsEmpty,
                         Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<TextBox
    Name="txtUserEntry"
    Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

and then remove any DataContext assignment from the UserControl's constructor.

See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25673948/1136211) (and many other similar) that discuss this topic in detail.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and extra info link.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to @Clemens answer:

To avoid setting `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}` for each control, provide a root element in the user control to get the DataContext.

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlBindingIssue.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlBindingIssue"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:TestUserControl,
                                              IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:TestUserControl}}}">
        <TextBox Width="100"
                 Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <!--  Other controls  -->
    </ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```