# Binding a StackPanel of custom user controls to an ObservableCollection of custom classes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, stackpanel

I have an ObservableCollection'<'NextBestAction'>' NextBestActions called NextBestActions, where NextBestAction is:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(NextBestActionTypeConverter))]
public class NextBestAction : IDisposable
{
    public bool isDismissable, dismissed, completed;
    public NextBestActionType type;
    public string title, description;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public NextBestAction()
    {

    }

    public NextBestAction(string title, string description)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static NextBestAction Parse(Card card)
    {
        if (card == null)
        {
            return new NextBestAction();
        }

        return new NextBestAction(card.Title.Text, card.Description.Text);
    }
}
```

I also have my own UserControl called Card, where Card is:

```
public partial class Card : UserControl
{
    public Card()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public Card(string title, string description)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.Title.Text = title;
        this.Description.Text = description;
    }

    public static Card Parse(NextBestAction nextBestAction)
    {
        if (nextBestAction == null)
        {
            return new Card();
        }

        return new Card(nextBestAction.title, nextBestAction.description);
    }
}
```

with the folling XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AdvancedTeller.Card"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdvancedTeller"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="300" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF333333" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="400">
<Grid Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="Title" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18.667" Margin="3"/>
    <TextBlock Name="Description"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Finally, I have defined a TypeConverter for NextBestAction as

```
public class NextBestActionTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    // Override CanConvertFrom to return true for Card-to-NextBestAction conversions. 
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(Card))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    // Override CanConvertTo to return true for NextBestAction-to-Card conversions. 
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(Card))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    // Override ConvertFrom to convert from a Card to an instance of NextBestAction. 
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        Card card = value as Card;

        if (card != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return NextBestAction.Parse(card);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Cannot convert '{0}' ({1}) because {2}", value, value.GetType(), e.Message), e);
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    // Override ConvertTo to convert from an instance of NextBestAction to Card. 
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType");
        }

        //Convert Complex to a string in a standard format.
        NextBestAction nextBestAction = value as NextBestAction;

        if (nextBestAction != null && this.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType) && destinationType == typeof(Card))
        {
            try
            {
                return Card.Parse(nextBestAction);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Cannot convert '{0}' ({1}) because {2}", value, value.GetType(), e.Message), e);
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

I am trying to bind the NextBestActions to a StackPanel, and force the NextBestActions to be represented in the UI as Cards.

So far, I have understood that I need at least this

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="50" >
    <ItemsControl Name="NextBestActionItems" ItemsSource="{Binding NextBestActions}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <AdvancedTeller:Card />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The code compiles and runs without any issues, and a Card is created and visible in the StackPanel for each item in the ObservableCollection, however, each Card's Title and Description are blank and won't take the data of their respective NextBestAction.

I feel like I'm 90% of the way there. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

UPDATE/EDIT 1: Currently the NextBestActionTypeConverter is not called/hit. If I remove the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate definition from the XAML, then the NextBestActionTypeConverter is called, but with destinationType as "string". I am trying to force/set the ItemsControl to understand that the itesm are to be represented as Cards.

UPDATE/EDIT 2 (Answer): Here are the snippets for the answer:

```
// Override ConvertTo to convert from an instance of NextBestAction to Card. 
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType");
        }

        //Convert Complex to a string in a standard format.
        NextBestAction nextBestAction = value as NextBestAction;

        if (nextBestAction != null && this.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType) && destinationType == typeof(Card))
        {
            try
            {
                return new Card();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Cannot convert '{0}' ({1}) because {2}", value, value.GetType(), e.Message), e);
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
```

and

```
public partial class Card : UserControl
{
    public Card()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and

```
<UserControl x:Class="AdvancedTeller.Card"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdvancedTeller"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="300" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF333333" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Width="400">
<Grid Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="Title" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18.667" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    <TextBlock Name="Description"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I notice your Title and Description textboxes in your `Card` UserControl do not have their Text bound to anything. Is this intentional (such as using Caiburn Micro), or an oversight?

Comment: Possibly an oversight. I thought I could set the Text of Title and Description in the Card's constructor, which would be called by TypeConverter. However, the TypeConverter is never called. If I remove the ItemTemplate in the XAML, then the TypeConverter is called, but with destination type "string". I want the ItemsControl to call the TypeConverter with destination type "Card"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few potential problem spots in your code that I can see.

First of all, it looks like you do not have full properties, with `get; set;` accessor methods, defined for `Title` and `Description` in your `NextBestAction` object.

If I recall correctly, WPF's binding system requires full properties with get/set accessors, and does not bind to fields that don't have them.

So

```
public string title, description;
```

Should become

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Another potential problem may be the fact you haven't bound the .Text property of your Title/Description textboxes in the `Card` UserControl.

So assuming you aren't using a framework that automatically creates Bindings based on the `.Name` property like Caliburn Micro, this code

```
<TextBlock Name="Title" ... />
<TextBlock Name="Description" ... />
```

Should be

```
<TextBlock Name="Title" Text="{Binding Title}" ... />
<TextBlock Name="Description" Text="{Binding Description}" ... />
```

Also, I'm pretty sure bindings are case-sensitive, so you want to be sure the case of your Bindings (or `Name` property if using Caliburn Micro) matches the case of your Properties.

And last of all, anytime I see a `UserControl` hardcode it's `.DataContext`, warning bells go off in my head. UserControls should not do this. They should get their DataContext from whatever code is using the control, and should not create their own. Get rid of the following lines of code that hardcodes the `.DataContext` in the `Card` UserControl, and then it will use whatever values are in the `NextBestActions` collection instead.

```
public Card()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this; // Bad!
}

public Card(string title, string description)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this; // Bad!
    this.Title.Text = title; // Should be replaced with bindings as above
    this.Description.Text = description; // Should be replaced with bindings as above
}
```

(As a side note, I have no idea what you're doing with that TypeConverter :) It's typically used to convert one type to another, such as changing the string `"Red"` to a `SolidColorBrush` with a `.Color` set to Red when you type something like `<StackPanel Background="Red" />`. I don't see a use for it with your current code and would recommend getting rid of it entirely unless you need it for some specific reason.)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I know why you are saying it, and I made your changes and it works perfectly! But I still don't fully understand why these changes would compile at all. How does the Card handle the incoming Title and Description from the TypeConverter, if the Card's constructor doesn't even need to accept them?

Comment: @MichaelDeLuca WPF applications have two layers: UI and Data (DataContext). Bindings are used to pull data from the Data layer into the UI layer. The data layer gets inherited by default from parent controls unless you specify otherwise by setting the `.DataContext` property, like you had in your code. I see this mistake so often from WPF beginners that I wrote a blog post to link to from SO  - [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). Feel free to check it out for more details :)

Comment: @MichaelDeLuca As for the TypeConverter, I didn't even recognize what it was at first, and is typically not used unless you are doing something more advanced with WPF. When you write something like `<StackPanel Background="Red" />`, what actually process is more like `var s = new StackPanel(); s.Background = "Red";`, however the problem here is that the `.Background` is a `Brush` property, and `"Red"` is a string. So a TypeConverter is used to automatically convert strings to Brush objects.

Comment: What I mean is, if you look at my edit which contains the modified snippets which makes this work, why does it _even_ work? Should I not have to define a Parser that set the Card's Title and Description and any other paramters of Card, based on what the underlying class is and has? Say, for example, that NextBestAction and NextBestProduct both have Title and Description, but I want one to be represented by a red background card, and the other by a green background card, is a Parser or special Card constructor not necessary to set such parameters?

Comment: @MichaelDeLuca When you set the ItemsSource, it tells WPF to loop through the collection and for each item create a `<ContentPresenter>` with the `.Content` property set to the object. So WPF tries to draw the object, which in this case is a `NextBestAction`. That is probably why the TypeConverter is being used when you don't specify a DataTemplate - it is trying to convert `NextBestAction` into a string so it can render it to the UI. Fixing the bindings in your UserControl is a different issue - let me know if you still have questions once you've read up on the `.DataContext` some more :)

Comment: @MichaelDeLuca And for your question *"What if I want to represent more than one different classes as Cards in the UI, where some have Title and some don't explicitly define Title?"*, I would recommend looking up "Custom Dependency Properties", where you create your own properties that can be bound to. Your UserControl would then look something like  like `<AdvancedTeller:Card Title="{Binding TitleProperty}" Description="{Binding DescriptionProperty}"  />`, where you tell it what properties to use.

Comment: I just finished reading your blog post. You have not only answered my question, but opened my eyes to how DataContext works.

Comment: @MichaelDeLuca Good to hear! The DataContext is very important when working with WPF, and is part of why I love the technology so much. Goodluck with your project :)

Comment: Sorry to extend this thread, not enough rep to move to chat. I am reading up on dependency properties, but before I run down that rabbit hole, I'd like to know if its the correct rabbit hole. I'd like to append other custom controls inside each Card and have the Card's logic and internals behave differently, depending on certain properties of the underlying NextBestAction. Will understanding and utilizing dependency properties help me achieve this? And finally, is the binding I created now two-way? How can I affect a NextBestAction property by interacting with the respective Card? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDeLuca Yes, most DependencyProperties default to using TwoWay databinding, and `TextBox.Text` is no exception.

Comment: As for your question about dependency properties, it's hard to tell without knowing exactly what kind View you want. I wrote an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25673948/302677) which explains my basic thought process - if it is very generic and meant to be used with many different object models (such as a Calendar, Popup, etc) I tend to use DependencyProperties. But if it is very specilized and always meant to be used with a specific object model, I will write the UserControl with the expectation that a specific DataContext is used with it. I think the 2nd sounds more the case here.

Comment: The second approach is also what I feel would be best, so I have been playing around with that in mind, assuming that Card's DataContext will always be of type NextBestAction (I can set it to an interface I will write, that will implemented by the handful of similar classes later). But in the meantime, I noticed that DataContext is null during Card's construction, yet non-null (its a NextBestAction) afterwards (i.e. when accessed in the MouseUp event for Card). Is this correct and intended? Which means, I can only modify the layout of a Card (Height, children, etc) after it has been Loaded.