# Binding Items in Tab Control ItemSource to a User Controls DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a tab control that is created from a list of objects and a WPF User control that I want to associate directly with one of these objects. I am creating this association as an Dependency Property in the control.

The binding error I get is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'WPFTester.Control' and 'WPFTester.TestClass'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='Control' (Name=''); target element is 'Control' (Name=''); target property is 'ClassDependency' (type 'TestClass')
```

It seems as though it changes its mind what the datacontext is before it binds.

The Main Window Creates the list of Objects and attaches them to a tab control. The Issue I am having regards the binding to the Control Dependency Object here.

```
XAML:

<Grid>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:Control ClassDependency="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>

Code-Behind:

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BindingList<TestClass> classes;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public BindingList<TestClass> Classes
    {
        get { return classes; }
        set
        {
            classes = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
            PropertyChangedEventArgs("Classes"));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        Classes = new BindingList<TestClass>
        {
            new TestClass() { Title = "123", Content="abc" },
            new TestClass() { Title = "456", Content="def" }
        };
    }
```

The rest of the classes are simple and I don't think the issue is in them but I will provide them anyways.

The Data Class is simple:

```
    public class TestClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

The User control displays a bound value and a constant value. It also presents a Dependency Property.

```
XAML:

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextDependency}" Margin="5"/>
    <TextBlock Text="I'm here"/>
</StackPanel>

Code-Behind:

public partial class Control : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClassDependencyProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ClassDependency",
        typeof(TestClass),
        typeof(Control));

    public TestClass ClassDependency
    {
        get { return (TestClass)GetValue(ClassDependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClassDependencyProperty, value); }
    }

    public Control()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try specifying the type which your `DataTemplate` represents. Like this: `<DataTemplate TargetType='{x:Type namespace:TestClass}'>...</DataTemplate>`.

Comment: `this.DataContext = this;` in the Control constructor prevents that `ClassDependency="{Binding}"` works as you expect.

Comment: You have an error: bind to TextDependency and not to ClassDependency

Comment: Thank you Clemens, that was the issue. Here is the full answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672037/how-to-correctly-bind-to-a-dependency-property-of-a-usercontrol-in-a-mvvm-framew?noredirect=1&lq=1